# swift 3.0: Extra argument in call

Tags: post, swift3, alamofire

I migrated my code from swift 2.3 to swift3, before it was working fine after migrating am facing extra argument in call issue.Any help is appreciable.Here is my code.

```
func POST(url: String, params: [String : AnyObject]) -> Future<JSON, NSError> {
        let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, self.buildAppUrl(url), parameters: params, encoding: .JSON, headers: self.requestHeaders())

        return self.makeRequest(request)
    }
```

Comment: @vadian, i checked with those answers,i tried to change my answer as below let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, self.buildAppUrl,  method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.JSON, headers: self.requestHeaders()) still am getting error.Please help me

Comment: @Vinathynvr If you have checked properly then your request should be like this. `let request = Alamofire.request(self.buildAppUrl(url), method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.requestHeaders())`

Comment: @NiravD,Thanks for ur reply,now am  getting extra arguement method in call error i changed the code to let request = Alamofire.request(self.buildAppUrl(_url), method:HTTPMethod.post,Parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.URL, headers:self.requestHeaders())